# Add entityFramework section with C#

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework-6, app-config

We have a WPF application which is extensible with external components developed in-house. Some external components requires new section (in this case, `EntityFrameworkSection`) to be added into the `app.config` of the WPF application during the installation of the component. However, `EntityFrameworkSection` doesn't seems to accessible as it is an internal class.

Our question is, is it possible for us to programmatically add `EntityFrameworkSection` into `app.config`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I'm happen to use EF6, I ended up using [code base configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/configuring/code-based) which is available since EF6. In my case, I'm trying to add configuration related to MySQL. Basically what we need to do is to derive from `DbConfiguration` and set it as the configuration for EF. Following is what I comes up with:

Deriving from `DbConfiguration`...

```cs
public class CustomDbConfiguration : DbConfiguration
{
    public CustomDbConfiguration()
    {
        SetProviderServices(MySqlProviderInvariantName.ProviderName, new MySqlProviderServices());
        SetProviderFactory(MySqlProviderInvariantName.ProviderName, new MySqlClientFactory());
    }
}
```

and use it like this:

```cs
class Program
{
    // 'DbConfiguration' should be treated as readonly. ONE AND ONLY ONE instance of 
    // 'DbConfiguration' is allowed in each AppDomain.
    private static readonly CustomDbConfiguration DBConfig = new CustomDbConfiguration();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Explicitly set the configuration before using any features from EntityFramework.
        DbConfiguration.SetConfiguration(DBConfig);

        using (var dbContext = new MySQLDb())
        {
            var dbSet = dbContext.Set<Actor>();

            // Read data from database.
            var actors = dbSet.ToList();
        }

        using (var dbContext = new SQLDb())
        {
            var dbSet = dbContext.Set<User>();

            // Read data from database.
            var users = dbSet.ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

My `app.config` only contains info for connection string, as follow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" />
  </startup>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MySQLDb" connectionString="server=localhost;port=3306;database=sakila;uid=some_id;password=some_password" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"/>
    <add name="SQLDb" connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=some_db;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```